# Columns not showinng in DataSet for dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, dynamic-sql

I have the following SP which works correctly when ran on its own:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sgetInvoiceHeaderDetails]

@InvoiceNo varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
SET FMTONLY ON;
    declare @sql varchar(max)

set @sql = 'SELECT IH.InvoiceNo, IH.InvoiceDate, IH.InvoiceTime, C.Name, R.Name AS Customer, IH.NetAmount, 
IM.Name AS Item, ID.UnitPrice, ID.Qty, ID.Total, ID.BatchNo
FROM InvoiceHeader AS IH INNER JOIN
InvoiceDetail AS ID ON IH.InvoiceNo = ID.InvoiceNo INNER JOIN
Customer AS C ON IH.CustomerId = C.Id INNER JOIN
Route AS R ON IH.RouteId = R.Id INNER JOIN
ItemMaster AS IM ON ID.ItemMasterId = IM.Id
WHERE IH.InvoiceNo IN ('+@InvoiceNo+')'
print @sql
exec (@sql)
END
```

The problem I'm having is that when I add a DataSet for a report, it pulls no fields/columns in the Fields section. I'm guessing it's due to the dynamic SQL?

How can I resolve that?

[image]

Comment: Change `exec (@sql)` to `exec @sql`

Comment: Do your tables have enough data?

Comment: Yes. There is data. When running SP in DB level data returning.

Comment: Compared to views, stored procs doesn't have a fixed column list. A SELECT-Statement does define columns. But you cannot SELECT from a Stored Proc. You can only specify the Parameters for the stored proc and see what it returns.

Comment: I'd take away the `print`... Silly question: Are you sure, your Wizard works against the right db? And one more question: Are you sure, that dynamic SQL in this case is the needed option? If you just need a solution for the `IN(... List of InvoiceNumbers ...)` there are better approaches... (and be aware of injection!)

Comment: With out dynamic sql data didn't retrieved

Comment: I'm quite sure you tried to fill something like `"3,7,12"` into the `IN-clause`. This won't work. Dynamic SQL is a possible, but surely a bad approach. You could read this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterize-an-sql-in-clause

Answer (score 1):

As statet in my comment you should avoid the dynamic approach.

Just to offer you a pure inline solution in SQL have a look at this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT, Caption VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(1,'Test 1'),(2,'Test 2'),(3,'Test 3'),(4,'Test 4'),(5,'Test 5');

DECLARE @WantToGet VARCHAR(100)='1,3,4';

WITH Splitted AS
(
    SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(@WantToGet,',','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS AsXml
)
,SplittedAsList AS
(
    SELECT The.Node.value('.','int') As ID
    FROM Splitted
    CROSS APPLY AsXml.nodes('/x') AS The(Node)
)
SELECT Caption
FROM @tbl AS tbl
INNER JOIN SplittedAsList sal ON sal.ID = tbl.ID;
```

The string `1,3,4` is splitted as a list. The `INNER JOIN` at the end is exactly the same as you wanted to achieve with the IN-clause.

This approach you can plcae within a table valued function (make sure to keep this as inline function!). This function is much better reusable everywhere.

The second recommandable approach would be the `CREATE TYPE`, bute this needs more action on application side...